# How do I prevent the overlapping of nodes in a d3 Radial tree when there are large number of nodes in unusual sizes?

Tags: d3.js

```
// d3 tree layout
tree = d3.tree()
    .size([360, Math.min(width, height) - 120])
    .separation((a, b) => a.depth === 0 ? 1 : (a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth);
}
```

Right now, this is how I am doing it. But in many cases, the nodes are being overlapped.[image]

Comment: An easy fix would be to decrease the size of the circles and squares.

Comment: I tried doing it during window resizing and changing the node diameters in the nodeUpdate section. Few cases it worked but it was still not a perfect solution.

Comment: Please update your questions with more details so that people can help you. Read [these guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).